# Redis | Replication and common disk storage

Tags: redis, replication, phpredis, nosql

I am just starting to use Redis for the first time. I have gone through the documentation and I came to know that Redis can be used in replication mode. But, I have some questions which are still un-answered. Let's have a quick view of use-case

- I have a clustered environment of Drupal 7 code base.
- There are two web servers web1 and web2 and two DB servers DB1 and DB2
- DB1 and DB2 are running in master-slave mode
- I have to setup Redis on both web1 and web2, web1 as master and web2 as slave
- I need same backend/disk storage for both master and slave

Is it possible to setup same backend/disk storage for both master and slave?
A solution can be that I use Redis on a single server, e.g on web1. In this case requests on web2 uses Redis cache of web1. In this case I will get a delay by network. I want to avoid this situation because I want to utilize full performance of Redis i.e reading from the memory.

Is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your master Redis instance is on Web1 then all writes will have to go here.  You can however read from the slave instance on Web2 locally.

http://redis.io/topics/replication